# Posts aren't loading correctly for multiple users

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My app isn't loading more posts correctly for the currently logged in user or when viewing other users. I'm new to rails and have had this error for a while. If anything else is needed just let me know and I'll get it.

This is the error trace

```
Started GET "/feed_content" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-11 10:53:14 -0700
Processing by UsersController#feed as */*
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL
LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `tokens' for nil:NilClass):
  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `user_has_provider?'
  app/models/feed.rb:26:in `twitter_posts'
  app/models/feed.rb:17:in `posts'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:70:in `feed'
```

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def feed
  @title = "Feed"
  @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  feed = Feed.new(@user)
  @providers = Providers.for(@user)
  @timeline = feed.posts(params[:twitter_pagination]) # line 70
  @unauthed_accounts = feed.unauthed_accounts
  @poster_recipient_profile_hash = feed.poster_recipient_profile_hash
  @commenter_profile_hash = feed.commenter_profile_hash

  @load_more_url = feed_content_path(
    :twitter_pagination => feed.twitter_pagination_id,
  )

  render 'show_feed'
end
```

feed.rb

```
class Feed
  include ApplicationHelper

  attr_reader :poster_recipient_profile_hash,
              :commenter_profile_hash,
              :unauthed_accounts,
              :twitter_pagination_id,

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
    @unauthed_accounts = []
  end

  def posts(twitter_pagination_id)
    TimelineConcatenator.new.merge(twitter_posts(twitter_pagination_id))
  end

  private

  def twitter_posts(twitter_pagination_id)
    twitter_posts = []
    if user_has_provider?('twitter', @user)
      twitter_timeline = Twitter::Timeline.new(@user)
      begin
        twitter_posts = twitter_timeline.posts(twitter_pagination_id).map { |post| Twitter::Post.from(post) }
        @twitter_pagination_id = twitter_timeline.last_post_id
      rescue Twitter::Error::Forbidden, Twitter::Error::Unauthorized
        @unauthed_accounts << "twitter"
      end
      twitter_posts
    else
      twitter_posts
    end
  end
```

apphelper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def user_has_provider?(provider, user = current_user)
    @user.tokens.by_name(provider).any?
  end  
end
```

token.rb

```
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :provider, presence: true
  validates :uid, presence: true

  belongs_to :user

  def self.by_name(name)
    where(provider: name)
  end

  def self.update_or_create_with_twitter_omniauth(id, auth)
    token = where(provider: auth["provider"], uid: auth["uid"]).first_or_initialize
    token.provider = auth["provider"]
    token.uid = auth["uid"]
    token.access_token = auth["extra"]["access_token"].token
    token.access_token_secret = auth["extra"]["access_token"].secret
    token.user_id = id
    token.save!
    token
  end

  def configure_twitter(access_token, access_token_secret)
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = '**********'
      config.consumer_secret = '********'
      config.access_token = access_token
      config.access_token_secret = access_token_secret
    end
    client
  end
end
```

feed_index.js

```
FeedIndex = {

  initialize: function () {
    var reloadOk = false;

    $.get("/feed_content").success(function (response) {
      var loadingMessage = $(".loading_message");
      loadingMessage.before(response);
      loadingMessage.hide();
    }).success(function () {
      reloadOk = true
    });

    $(document).scroll(function () {
      var scrollbarPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
      var documentHeight = $(this).height();

      if (documentHeight - scrollbarPosition < 7500 && reloadOk === true) {
        $(".loading_message").show();
        var nextPageUrl = $(".load_posts_link a").attr("href");
        reloadOk = false;
        $.get(nextPageUrl).success(function (response) {
          reloadOk = true;
          $(".load_posts_link").replaceWith(response);
          $(".loading_message").hide();
        });
      }
    });
```

EDIT*****

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers, :bio, :feed, :settings
  end
end

get '/feed_content', to: 'users#feed', as: :feed_content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not defining your `@user` variable - hence it showing up as `nil`

I think this is because you're using a `collection` route (meant for multiple records), as opposed to a `member` route (for individual records):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   get :feed_content, action: :feed, as: :feed_content #-> domain.com/users/:user_id/feed_count
end
```

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
  def feed
    ...
    @user = User.find params[:user_id]
    ...
  end
end
```

This *should* permit you to populate the `@user` variable, which you'll then be able to *send* that user to your helper. Currently, your helper is trying to use `@user`, when really it just needs to use the data passed to it:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
  def user_has_provider?(provider, user = current_user)
    user.tokens.by_name(provider).any?
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't put this before, but I was using a `member` route. Is there a problem using `member` and `get` to call out a custom route?

Comment: No problems at all - it's in the routing docs if you'd like to clarify

Answer (score 1):

in apphelper.rb

`def user_has_provider?(provider, user = current_user)
    @user.tokens.by_name(provider).any?
  end`

I would use the user passed in params (without the @): `user.tokens.by_name(provider).any?`

Comment: Didn't do it, still the same

Comment: in user_controller.rb try to replace `@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])` by `@user = User.find(params[:id])`
if it raises then you are retrieving users that does not exists

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User without an ID):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:67:in `feed' is the new error

Comment: Then it means that the query that hits the feed action in the user_controller does not always send an existing user through the params. I would suggest to not initialize a new Feed when unable to retrieve the user from your db.

Comment: It works if I pass session[:user_id] in instead of params[:id] for @user = User.find(params[:id]) but only for the current user and it messes up viewing other users' feeds.